# Why aren't there any passive mobs spawning in my single player world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There used to be a bunch of pigs and sheep and cows and chickens, but ever since I've been building everywhere, they've vanished. I tried to create patches of grass with torches on them to get them to spawn, but they still won't — what am I doing wrong?

(I'm playing Minecraft 1.8.)

Comment: You don't happen to have loads and loads of tamed wolves, do you?

Comment: this is my first world and i havent seen ANY wolves (peaceful)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Passive mob spawning has changed in version 1.8. Animals now spawn when a new chunk is generated and they don't despawn. However, there seem to be some disagreement as to what happens if you kill all the animals around you. Some say that they don't respawn while others claim that they do but do so very slowly.

The best thread I've seen about this is [this one](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/639466-persistent-animals-breeding-spawning-and-despawning-myths-disproven/page__p__8381526#entry8381526) posted mere hours ago. It seems to confirm what you see, that animals don't respawn at all. **UPDATE:** The same thread now seems to confirm that they do respawn, just very slowly.

Also, I think everyone agree that animals don't spawn in ocean biomes at all. I have played on a couple of islands far out to sea myself and have never seen animals there.

In version 1.9 breeding of animals will be introduced. Hopefully that will clear things up.

Comment: wow thank you very much for this i also read the whole other fourm, im having problems with no animals in one of my single player worlds and i found out thanks to you and the other guy that they rarely spawn back i guess im going to have to convert to those melon and wheat farms :D

Comment: Hmm, animals always respawn very *very* fast for me...  On my SMP server, you can't walk 2 chunks in any direction without encountering ~30 cows/pigs/chickens/sheep.  And they respawn every time I go anywhere.  I'm collecting stacks of beef and leather very fast.  So I don't think they seriously nerfed passive mob spawning.  (unless it's an SMP glitch?)

Comment: Well, just thought I might add that you might mean 1.0 instead of 1.9 and that how is he supposed to breed when he can't find a single animal?

Comment: Actually I meant beta 1.9. This is an old question.

Answer (score 6):

Well, if there are wolves around, they will eat passive mobs. Try looking in a lake, because piggies tend to swim. ;)

Comment: I have yet to see any wolves -- im in peaceful mode

Comment: @nodebunny - Wolves spawn on peaceful.

Comment: I havent seen any wolves yet. what should i do?

Comment: Well, wolves seem to be rarer than diamond, so just keep looking. If you have a bone with you and you find one, right-click it and it will become your pet and will not de-spawn.

Answer (score 2):

here are a few suggestions:

- Generate a new world and look for mobs
- Leave minecraft on with the inventory open while you go eat lunch or something
- Force an update

Comment: wont clearing the .minecraft folder nuke my saved worlds???

Comment: yes. you can always back up the save worlds then clear the .minecraft folder, ensuring you have a completely clean minecraft.

Comment: store my saved world and nuke the other stuff?

Comment: the other stuff is just game files, which would just be re-downloaded anyway to ensure you have a clean minecraft. BTW i removed that suggestion.

Comment: Forcing an update will not nuke your saved worlds. Don't worry.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't always put it in peaceful mode,ALMOST no Mods spawn in peaceful mode,that's why it's *peaceful* try going to easy or normal or if not make a new world but don't make it in "Creative"