# How come animals don't spawn near my house?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why aren't there any passive mobs spawning in my single player world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30628/why-arent-there-any-passive-mobs-spawning-in-my-single-player-world)

In Minecraft, I settled next to a pretty mountain range, planted tress, gave plenty of light and I even have a little wheat garden. I'm having occasional problems with food shortage due to the lack of animals despite that the area is well lit and so on.

How come animals don't spawn then? What do I do to make them spawn?

Answer (score 1):

That space just isn't a big enough space to have any impact on the *huge* area that they could spawn.

Also they won't spawn within a certain distance of you. So try moving away for a bit.