# How can I make my villagers more pacifistic?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I'm using [MineColony](https://sites.google.com/site/minecolony/) to get some NPC's that are actually useful.  But, they're being a little *too* useful.  Specifically, the women are slaughtering all the wildlife.

[image]

Many pigs used to roam this field.

A few versions ago, I would've had no problem with this, but with the fairly recent animal spawning changes, I'm afraid I might end up like [this guy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30628/why-arent-there-any-passive-mobs-spawning-in-my-single-player-world).

How can I prevent a pigpocalypse?

Comment: IIRC spawning was fixed in release.

Comment: As a fellow pig, I hope you find a solution soon

Answer (score 1):

Do the villagers go inside fences? If not, then get a few pigs, move to a place quite a ways from the village, and fence the pigs. The villagers can't get in and the pigs can't get out. Do this with the other animals you want to farm.

If they can get into fences, then you might have to kill the women. :(

Comment: Don't forget about children.

Answer (score 1):

1. Protect your pigs inside a barn
2. Organize your barn secretly

Answer (score 0):

- Put the pigs somewhere only you can access like a shack made out of stone and an iron door. Use a button to get in and out.
- Kill the offending villagers indirectly by pushing them off a cliff so that iron golems don't attack you.

Answer (score -1):

Kill them >:( or find a place where you can freely kill pigs.

Comment: These aren't regular NPCs...are you sure killing them will have no negative effects?  (Even if these *were* regular NPCs, wouldn't killing them anger the iron golems?)

Comment: If the NPCs are from a mod,killing them will turn local NPCs hostile but if you run away(let's say somewhere that the village can't be seen)and then return they will be passive.And in regards to the golems,if you have a diamond sword they come down quickly!