# Do passive mobs breed or respawn naturally in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why aren’t there any passive mobs spawning in my single player world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30628/why-arent-there-any-passive-mobs-spawning-in-my-single-player-world)

I've noticed that on Minecraft multiplayer servers (since mob breeding was introduced), there tends to be a large "dead zone" around spawn, due to over-harvesting of mobs by players. Do passive mobs (e. g., sheep, cows, pigs, chickens) respawn or breed to make up for the population loss? I've noticed that ocelots appear to increase in number over time, but I still want to know whether the same applies to the other passive mobs.

Answer (score 1):

> Very rarely, new animals can spawn in already generated chunks, just
> like monsters do. When animals spawn in this way, they do so only on
> grass blocks with light level 9 or greater above them. This is also a
> requirement for animals spawning from monster spawners. Unlike
> monsters, animals do not spontaneously despawn, except for wild
> ocelots and wolves (which can despawn only when they are hostile).

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Animal_spawning)

Comment: You may want to move this over to the original question.

Comment: Just how rare is the spawning of passive mobs?

Comment: @AndersonGreen Very rarely...

Comment: Wolves despawn when they are passive and untamed.