# Why no animals?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my Minecraft private survival game I've built my house in a small valley, and I'm surviving on a small wheat and watermelon farm. This is because there are no animals. There are other mobs like Creepers, but not a single pig, cow, or chicken in sight.

Why are there no animals spawning?

Comment: look more. animals spawn randomly, eventually you will find some but you need to keep looking. I've had games where there were no cows within 1k in any direction of my area, boy leading them back home was a pain in the rear

Comment: Can you spawn them with eggs? Please switch to Creative and test this.

Comment: Related: [Why aren't there any passive mobs spawning in my single player world?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30628/why-arent-there-any-passive-mobs-spawning-in-my-single-player-world)

Answer (score 1):

Animals spawn in daylight or high levels of light on the surface, and your valley is probably darker than the surrounding flatlands, with less grass as well.  The shallow daytime light and the high probability that you're surrounded by stone walls is probably the cause of your troubles.

Try moving your home to the top of the valley, and look around in grassy areas - animal mobs spawn more frequently in large stretches of grasslands, but you'll also find them in almost any other terrain as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you look around the whole Minecraft area, then what you can do, is you can start a new world, make it Creative mode, do /summon EntityChicken 15 x: y: z:, or EntityCow 15 x: y: z:, and so on. That makes it to where you have a lot of animals, so you can breed. Then go back into survival, and survive in your animal-filled world.

Answer (score 0):

Animals spawn in different areas, some in very bizarre places too.
Still might I suggest go to places you think they'll spawn and set traps a.k.a Holes in the ground with Torches around them and in them on the side walls. Make it very deep so the animal can't get out then make a trench to your home.

Sorry if this wasn't very helpful, but this is all I know, as I am pretty new to minecraft myself and only play creative mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just travel a couple of hundred blocks until you find a plains biome, then run around there. There will be plenty of animals.